How do clock signal generators prevent race conditions?
With full understanding that wikipedia is not a completely reliable source, this wikipedia article explains that a clock signal prevents race conditions by making components update at the same time.
However, it does not provide a citation nor explanation for why this would fix race conditions between components. In fact, I'd assume that it'd make it worse, because everything is now executing at the same time, not sequentially.
I am unable to find any other sources that explain this, because all that comes up regards multithreaded programming instead.

The problem with asynchronous design is that you can have multiple units  producing a result at similar times, and that depending on luck, or changes in timing delays, one or the other might finish first. It doesn't help to know how long any particular process may take if you don't know when they started.
Having a synchronous design, with a global clock signal, allows you to know when each logic process starts. Now you can use knowledge of how long each takes to know when they are going to finish.
In practice, we do not know exactly how long each process will take, but we use a guaranteed maximum time, from the data sheet of the component, to know when it must have finished by, in order to deliver the next clock and start the next process.
Any logic designer, within a few days of starting a design, will know their way through the data sheets' tables of tsu, thold, and tprop for all the components they are using. FWIW I start dreaming them. If you respect the setup and hold times, then everything should 'just work', and the design is easy to do, or at least possible.
Sometimes a logic process might take a particularly long or uncertain time, so we break it up into several clocks, so-called pipelining, in order to keep control of its delays. Typical things needing this are a fetch from memory, or a multiplication.
Of course as winny says in comments, having a clock and synchronous design isn't a sufficient condition for avoiding race, you can still mess up the design by not allowing the time that the specifications require.

Can you add that a clocked network isn’t a guarantee against race condition? The designer needs to make sure the clock signal arrives after data has settled.

It's really not the clock generators that prevent race conditions, it's the logic blocks themselves that use a clock signal to do things synchronously.
The logic blocks (and the clock rate) need to be designed so that each logic block has enough time to take the inputs and provide the outputs in one clock cycle, so the data between logic blocks is stable with every clock cycle.
If the logic is asynchronous, then it is possible that when some input somewhere changes, it causes changes to ripple through the logic circuit, and some outputs update earlier than others, so if some output depends on the same input signal but processed through different depth of logic chain, it is possible that some gates have a glitch on the output because inputs update at different moment in time.
